# Deploying React Native: Couldn't get the native call queue: bridge configuration isn't available. This shouldn't be possible. Congratulations

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I followed the [Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content) article and uploaded my app to the Google Play store. It crashes on load with:

> Couldn't get the native call queue: bridge configuration isn't
>   available. This shouldn't be possible. Congratulations

[image: crash report screenshot]

Did I miss a step?

Comment: Where you able to run the release apk before uploading to play store?

Comment: Found the answer. Apparantly I used the "Android Studio" generate a signed APK option instead of the "./gradlew assembleRelease"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. With Android apps I always generate a Signed APK via the "Generate Signed APK" option in **Android Studio**. I didn't know that in order to deploy with React Native you need to run:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Make sure you add the APK signing config. Otherwise the APK won't be signed and Google Play won't accept it (claiming the "zip is not aligned"). In the build.gradle (app module) add:

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersi...
    buildToolsVersi...
    ...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/Users/dht/filepath.jks")
            storePassword "*****"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "*****"
        }
    }

 buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ...
    }
}
```